# What does $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n .\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$ converge to at x= 1 and x = -1

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series

This is what I did.

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n .\frac{1^{2n+1}}{2n+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n .\frac{1}{2n+1}$

Now I broke it up to positive and negative.

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n .\frac{1}{2n+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4n+1} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4n+3}$

If I take the limits of of both of these I get zero... this does not feel right to me.

Answer (score 1):

At $x=1$, the sum converges to $\pi/4$.  At $x=-1$, however, the sum diverges.

$$\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^{2 n+1}}{2 n+1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n x^{2 n} = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

So the sum is

$$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

For $x=-1$, you get

$$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1-x^2}$$

which diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Use Ablelian summation, and it converges properly, not absolutely. Hence, you can not divide it into two parts which are infinity.